# How to set keyboard hover in select2

Tags: jquery-select2

How to set keyboard hover in select2. I have mouse hover and work fine, but keyboard no? When i use arrow down and press enter he select secound element and thats work fine, but no hover effect.

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: How about using the [onSelect event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp)?